# hibernate oracle - some entity tables not map

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I'm working on a java spring mvc application that use hibernate 4.3.10 for connecting to oracle 11g database. This is a part of my persistence configuration class:

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() throws SQLException {
    BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.10.1.23:1521:orcl");
    dataSource.setUsername("sys as sysdba");
    dataSource.setPassword("password");

    return dataSource;
}
```

And I used two annotations `@Entity` and `@Table(name = "table_name", schema = "TEST")` on top of each entity class. But when I run the project, some of entities not map in the database and I got `table xxx not found` in the log. Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

I tested this project on mysql before and everything was ok, but I have this problem in oracle database.

Comment: what you have set for hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto property in config file? I guess it is set to update. Anyway please post the stacktrace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put each column name inside a `[]` and the problem resolved. For example I changed `@Column(name = "id")` into `@Column(name = "[id]")`.